# Getting P(X) from Joint Probability Table P(X, Y)

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution

I am trying to get the P(X) from this joint probability P(X,Y) table:

```
   X=1  X=2  X=3
```

Y=a 0.10 0.20 0.30

Y=b 0.05 0.15 0.20

I think the formula to find this is just to add P(X=1) + P(X=2) + P(X=3) which would make P(X) equal to 1.

Is the answer really just that straightforward though? I felt confident about it until I started working on P(X|Y) which I think would then also be equal to 1 if I use the formula P(X|Y) = P(X ∩ Y) / P(Y).

Comment: I don't follow this. Are you trying to get P(X=x), for some specific x? Which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ is a random variable. So you're likely looking for the probability mass function of $X$, rather than the probability that $X$ "occurs," or takes on a value. The probability that $X$ takes on some value is 1, just like the probability that "age" takes on some value is 1.

What I think you want is to find $P(X=1)$, $P(X=2)$, and $P(X=3)$, just like $P(X,Y)$ showed all combinations of $P(X=x, Y=y)$.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that makes way more sense. So then just to clarify, P(X) would actually have three answers right? And I guess P(X|Y) would then have six answers to cover all the possible values of X and Y?

Comment: That's correct. P(X) might be better written as P(X=x) and P(X|Y) might be better written as P(X=x|Y=y). You want to find the corresponding probabilities for all combinations of x and y. Also note that P(X=1|Y=b) is not 0.05 - rather it's 0.125. This is because the sum of P(X=x|Y=a) over all x should sum to one and the sum of P(X=x|Y=b) over all x should sum to one, by the definition of a conditional probability.